# C programming: Delete specific value stored in Array

Tags: c, arrays

Let us consider an array (say, `int a[25];`).
Later with the help of some loop I start storing the user input in this array.

At some point of time if user choose to delete the value he just entered from the array.

How can I do that for the user of my program.

I can make that 0, but 0 is also a value he could enter; so I simply want to make it NULL or with some garbage value, as it was when I initialized the array.

Comment: Setting it to `0` is just as good as any other garbage value.

Comment: `Arrays in C are stored as a contiguous block of memory, so you can't just remove an element.` Use linked list.

Comment: `NULL` is equivalent to 0 when talking about integers. You'll need to implement some type of counter.

Comment: @ColeCameron: `NULL` may be defined as `0` or as `((void*)0)`. `NULL` is specifically intended to be used as a null *pointer* constant. It should not be treated as an integer value.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'm aware, but within the context of his question, he wants to assign `NULL` to an integer. I was pointing out that this would not functionally be any different than the 0 scenario he stated he wanted to avoid.

Comment: @ColeCameron: If `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)` (which is perfectly legal), then assigning `NULL` to an integer is a constraint violation.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'm in agreement with you that it's a bad practice, but my original comment was meant to inform him of why his idea logically was a bad idea. Depending on his compiler, assigning `NULL` to an integer may not even warn about this 'constraint violation' (gcc does not, for example).

Comment: @ColeCameron: To be clear, assigning `NULL` to an integer isn't a constraint violation if `NULL` is defined as `0` -- though as we both agree it's horrid style. (But at least on my system, gcc (`<stddef.h>` is provided by gcc, not by glibc) defines `NULL` as `((void*)0)`, and `int n = NULL;` does trigger a warning.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Hmmm, strange that gcc gave you a warning while I did not get one (I did have `-Wall` on). I verified also that NULL was defined as a pointer rather than 0 by running the preprocessor. I did get a warning from clang when compiling the same program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete an element from an array. In C arrays are stored as a contiguous block of memory, so you can't just remove an element. You can use any of the following options:

1. Use some unused value like `-1` to mark the element as deleted.
2. Use separate array to keep track of deleted elements.
3. Use linked list to store your elements(Recommend option).

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If you define

```
int a[25];
```

then `a` consists of 25 `int` elements.  Each element, once you assign a value to it, retains that value until it's reassigned, or until the array ceases to exist. You can't "delete" a value from an array. There is no special `NULL` value for integers as there is for pointers.

You can pick a special value that denotes an "empty" element (perhaps `INT_MIN`) -- but then you won't be able to store that value as data. Or you can use another data structure, perhaps an array of `bool`, to keep track of whether the current value of each element of `a` is valid or not.